# Creating linq expression as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I use repository pattern design.

And entity framework in my project.

Here is the method from Remository class:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Entities.Where(predicate);
}
```

In this row I fetch from database all rows from SensorsMeasure table where      SensorUnitId is 5:

```
    public void deleteItem(int sensorId, UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
         sensorId=5;
         var items = unitOfWork.SensorsMeasure.Find(sensorId);            
    }
```

But in this row:

```
public void deleteItem(int sensorId, UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
```

I get this error:

```
cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<SensorObservation.Data.SensorsMeasure, bool>>' SensorObservation.Model
```

How can I write parameter for Find() method that fetches all records from table where SensorUnitId is 5.

Comment: What you're looking for is `lambda expressions` Check this out to learn about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get exeception is that your `Find` method expects a predicate expression as an argument, while you tried to pass integer, using `Find` in `delete item`. So, you need to write something like this:

```
public void deleteItem(int sensorId, UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
     sensorId=5;
     var items = unitOfWork.SensorsMeasure.Find(sm => sm.Id == sensorId);            
}
```

Besides, you'd notice, that `sm.Id` shoul be replaced, according to name of your Id property in EF model.

PS: AFAIK, it's not a good practice to use camel case, when naming your methods in c#. Try `DeleteItem` instead of `deleteItem`. Also, not sure that you need to inject an instance  of UnitOfWork class as an argument directly into `deleteItem` method. Consider passing it into constructor of a class, which implements `deleteMethod`.

Comment: Usually we require some basic effort for solving this issue. Additionally, it's worth adding `local functions` recently added to C#. It'll be more efficient and readable